# How to freeze mutable default parameter values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, metaprogramming, mutability

Python chose to follow the design decision which evaluates the function's signature only once. So this code:

```py
def test(x=[]):
    x.append(5)
    return x

print(test())
print(test())
```

Prints:

> [5]
>
> [5, 5]

I know it is possible to use `None` as a default value, and to change the parameter value inside the function if it is `None.`

---

How can I write some code that **change the behavior of `test`**, in a way that the default parameter would be reevaluated every time I call the function? The solution can include decorators and use classes as the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the function's `__default__` property to "freeze" defaults (and `__kwargs__` to "freeze" default keyword arguments):

```
def freeze_defaults(func):
     defaults = func.__defaults__
     kwdefaults = func.__kwdefaults__
     @functools.wraps(func) 
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
         func.__defaults__ = copy.deepcopy(defaults) 
         func.__kwdefaults__ = copy.deepcopy(kwdefaults)
         return func(*args, **kwargs) 
     return wrapper
```

Now:

```
@freeze_defaults
def test(x=[]):
    x.append(5)
    return x

print(test())
print(test())
```

Prints:

> [5]
>
> [5]

And even:

```
@freeze_defaults
def test(x=['hello!']):
    x.append(5)
    return x

print(test())
print(test())
```

Prints:

> ['hello!', 5]
>
> ['hello!', 5]

Comment: This introduces a thread-safety bug. If another thread interrupts `wrapper` between the `func.__defaults__` assignment and the call to `func`, two threads may end up using the same `__defaults__`. [Here's a demonstration](https://ideone.com/1NgEUm), using a `time.sleep` call to get the threads to interrupt each other in the right spot.

Comment: It also fails on keyword-only arguments, which use `__kwdefaults__` rather than `__defaults__`. [Here's a demonstration.](https://ideone.com/EFu9Mp)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback. Updated the function to support kwdefaults.